# ArrayList, LinkedList и переключение с одного на другой

Tags: java, list, коллекции, linked-list

Прочитал в книге:
На стадии планирования в программы вы можете выбрать список LinkedList, а потом, в процессе оптимизации, переключиться на ArrayList. Благодаря абстрактному характеру интерфейса List такой переход потребует минимальных изменений в коде.

1. Кто с этим сталкивался?
2. Как понять переключиться, это когда мы    создали ArrayList
   допустим,    а потом в ходе программы захотели    поменять его на
   LinkedList?
3. Приведите пример, можно небольшой, я просто ознакомиться хочу и
   понять хотя бы чуть-чуть, чтобы иметь в этом представление хоть
   какое-то.

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private List<String> CreateStringList()
{
  return new ArrayList<String>();
}

List<String> list = CreateStringList();
//много кода, работающего со списком
```

Потом, из каких-то соображений, выяснилось, что лучше было бы использовать `LinkedList<String>`. Меняем:

```
private List<String> CreateStringList()
{
  return new LinkedList<String>();
}
```

так как переменная `list` объявлена как `List<String>`, и оба типа списков реализуют `List<String>`.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван бегите из этой компании

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван вы из какого города?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Омск

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван по-моему так делают для того чтобы тупо заработать на умных парнях, при этом ничего в них не вкладывая

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Ну мне за это деньги платят, сижу и после работы часа 3-4, правда если бы помогали я бы очень быстро развивался, а то иногда сижу и есть куча вопросов и с технологией где с их помощью я за 10 минут пойму что да как работает и смогу уже что либо делать, но так как мне реально помочь некому я ковыряю сам, но дольше. Иногда днями сижу))

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я получу хотя бы 1 год в трудовую, подтяну всё что можно по Java, Spring потом схожу сдам экзамен Оракл и уже буду искать хорошую контору :). Если есть советы можете дать :), но идея о  смене компании покамись отсутствует потому что здесь платят деньги + дают иногда много времени чтобы я просто сидел и ковырялся + есть время даже читать по 40-50 страниц в день (книги).

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван я работаю программистом 12й год, половина моего рабочего времени ежедневно уходит на изучение книг и интернета, так что не обольщаетесь =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ неее, я просто о том, что время дают :)))), а так стараюсь :)

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Есть совет: перестать использовать слово "покамись" ).

Comment: @Igor понял, принял :)